# insertSublayer: below: stops tableview data from loading

Tags: iphone, ios5

This is a really strange problem but I am looping through a small array of buttons and setting gradients like you typically would:

```
    UIButton *currentButton = [buttons objectAtIndex:forAct];
    [currentButton.layer insertSublayer:layer atIndex:0];
```

I've obviously pre-made the layer and it all works fine.  Except I need my app to change the layers periodically, so I tried changing the bottom line to this:

```
    [currentButton.layer insertSublayer:layer below:currentButton.titleLabel.layer];
```

Which works the way I'd like it to except that one line prevents my UITableView data from loading throughout the rest of the view.  None of the tableviews are blocked or covered in any way by the buttons, and I'm a little perplexed.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Note that I wound up being able to accomplish what I needed to with insertSublayer: atIndex:[currentbutton.layer.sublayers count] - 1 but I'm still wondering why this all happened in the first place!